# Time fixed effects on Stata and R

Tags: r, stata

I've looked at many resources but can't seem to find an answer to this.
Basically I have various time series related to weather and would like to perform an OLS estimation. As a simple example:

y=constant+b1*rain+b2*sunshine

The data are hourly and spans 5 years. The amount of rain and sunshine that occur at a given hour are related to the amount of the same variable in the preceding hour so I address this either with an autoregressive process or by first differencing the equation above and dropping the constant.

However with weather there are also hourly patterns at play (for example, more sunshine at given times of the day), monthly patterns and yearly patterns (some months and years have uncharacteristic amounts of sunshine or rain). For this reason I would like to use time fixed effects, which would essentially be dummy variables for each hour-month-year of the sample. Assuming the sample had 5 years this would mean having 5years * 12 months * 24 hours for a total of 1440 fixed effects dummies.

The question is if there is any way to create these dummies automatically in the regression command? Or to create the dummies prior to running the regression, and how would I do these steps of creating them and then include the 1440 dummies in the command?
I'm open to doing this in either Stata or R, so if you know how to do it in either of these it would be much appreciated

TLDR: how do I create 1440 time fixed effects dummies (one for each hour over 5 years), and then use it in the regression command?

Comment: Yes, the `plm` function in the `plm` package let's you specify entity and time fixed effects. If you post your dataset by copy and pasting the output of `dput(my_data)`, I might be able to show you how to use it.

Comment: Hour-month-year seems like a strange grain at which to define dummies. Do you really want to estimate separate effects for 2-3am in February 2012 and 2-3am in February 2013?

Comment: @useR the output of that command is far too large, I assume you only need the last few rows:
Names = c("date", "rain", 
"temp", "clouds"), row.names = c(NA, 52608L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @Gregor Yes I know it is not very conventional but it makes sense to me in my specific research

Comment: @franmanuel That's not a valid `dput` output...If the dataset is too large, subset it, then `dput` the results. Please include the full output starting from: `structure(c(...` and copy that into your question (not as a comment)

Comment: Despite the fact that on SO you really should provide some code -- if you're about to apply any weights for regression rather take a look at the `lfe` package and the `felm()` function therein, from my experience `plm` doesn't like weights (ymmv).

Comment: Rain and sun don't know what month people say it is. TIme of year is, however, a climatic driver.

Answer (score 0):

**In Stata**: `reghdfe` seems perfect for this. I made some example data with the structure you specified:

```
clear 
set obs 100000
gen hour = floor(runiform()*24)+1
gen year = floor(runiform()*5) + 1990
gen month = floor(runiform()*12)+1

gen outcome = rnormal()
```

Then using "`#`" in `reghdfe` we can include fixed effects for the interactions of the variables in the absorb() option:

```
reghdfe outcome, absorb(hour#year#month)
```

In the output, you can verify that the number of categories is what you wanted, 1,440:

```
HDFE Linear regression                            Number of obs   =    100,000
Absorbing 1 HDFE group                            F(   0,  98560) =          .
                                                  Prob > F        =          .
                                                  R-squared       =     0.0142
                                                  Adj R-squared   =    -0.0002
                                                  Within R-sq.    =     0.0000
                                                  Root MSE        =     1.0010

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     outcome | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |  -.0020881   .0031653    -0.66   0.509    -.0082921    .0041158
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Absorbed degrees of freedom:
-------------------------------------------------------------+
         Absorbed FE | Categories  - Redundant  = Num. Coefs |
---------------------+---------------------------------------|
     hour#year#month |      1440           0        1440     |
-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`regress` can also do this but needs an `egen group` step to make a numeric identifier for the intersection because it doesn't use the hashtags. Using `regress` you would get the same result with

```
egen hourXyearXmonth = group(hour year month)
regress outcome, absorb(hourXyearXmonth)
```